# Ruby gem installation error after OSX Yosemite and Xcode 6 installation

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, xcode6

I tried installing a gem like I did before installing Yosemite, but now I'm getting an error:

/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:159:in `synchronize': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Ext::BuildError)

ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

deadlock; recursive locking

This is the command I wrote:

```
sudo gem install mysql2
```

This is the message it appears in the terminal:

> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/autotest-fsevent-0.2.9 for inspection.
>   Results logged to
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-14/2.0.0/autotest-fsevent-0.2.9/gem_make.out
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/autotest-fsevent-0.2.9 for inspection.
>   Results logged to
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-14/2.0.0/autotest-fsevent-0.2.9/gem_make.out
>     from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:159:in
>   `build_extension'     from
>   /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:198:in`block in
>   build_extensions'     from
>   /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `each'    from
>   /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in`
>   build_extensions'    from
>   /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1436:in `block in
>   build_extensions'     from
>   /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/user_interaction.rb:45:in`use_ui'
>     from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1434:in
>   `build_extensions'    from
>   /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb:60:in`
>   build_extensions'    from
>   /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:56:in
>   `contains_requirable_file?'   from
>   /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:925:in`block in
>   find_inactive_by_path'    from
>   /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `each'  from
>   /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in`find'  from
>   /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in
>   `find_inactive_by_path'   from
>   /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:185:in`try_activate'    from
>   /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:132:in
>   `rescue in require'   from
>   /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in`
>   require'     from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:601:in
>   `load_yaml'   from
>   /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:328:in`load_file'
>     from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:197:in
>   `initialize'  from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:289:in`new'
>     from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:289:in `configuration'
>     from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:63:in`run'
>     from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:38:in
>   `block in build'  from
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tempfile.rb:324:in`
>   open'    from
>   /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:17:in
>   `build'   from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:161:in`
>   block (2 levels) in build_extension'     from
>   /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:160:in `chdir'   from
>   /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:160:in`block in
>   build_extension'  from
>   /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:159:in `synchronize'
>     from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:159:in`
>   build_extension'     from
>   /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:198:in `block in
>   build_extensions'     from
>   /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in`each'    from
>   /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in
>   `build_extensions'    from
>   /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1436:in`block in
>   build_extensions'     from
>   /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/user_interaction.rb:45:in `use_ui'
>     from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1434:in`
>   build_extensions'    from
>   /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb:60:in
>   `build_extensions'    from
>   /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:56:in`
>   contains_requirable_file?'   from
>   /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:925:in `block in
>   find_inactive_by_path'    from
>   /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in`each'  from
>   /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `find'  from
>   /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in`
>   find_inactive_by_path'   from
>   /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:185:in `try_activate'    from
>   /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:132:in`
>   rescue in require'   from
>   /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in
>   `require'     from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:601:in`
>   load_yaml'   from
>   /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:328:in `load_file'
>     from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:197:in`
>   initialize'  from
>   /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:74:in `new'   from
>   /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:74:in`
>   do_configuration'    from
>   /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:39:in `run'   from
>   /usr/bin/gem:21:in`'

I am using OSX 10.10 and Xcode 6 Beta.

Do any of you guys have any idea as to what to do about this?

Comment: does a newer version of ruby help?

Answer (score 3):

I had a same problem when I installed mysql via bitnami, Looks like you do not have all required mysql libraries .

I used [brewsh](http://brew.sh/) and reinstalled mysql by

```
brew install mysql

sudo gem install mysql2
```

Also you need to load the dynamic library in your .profile file in the home directory, you can achieve this by adding these lines in .profile file .

```
export PATH=$PATH:$MYSQL
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Applications/mysql/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

In the above two lines of code

/Applications/mysql/lib , is the path where your mysql libraries are installed , in yours it might be different please check and use as per your environment

Comment: @JAR.JAR.beans, its a mac system, which had the issue, with out sudo how will you access mysql libraries or system files,

Comment: Since you install mysql with brew without sudo, it means the owner the the mysql client libs is not the root, your user can read these libs without sudo.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. Downgrading to ruby 1.9.3 with RVM fixed the issue for me on 10.10 Yosemite - here are the steps taken:

```
$ \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash
$ source /Users/shedali/.rvm/scripts/rvm
$ rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang
$ gem install [packagename]
```

Comment: I don't know who downvoted this, but this worked fine for me. THANK YOU! :)